# why does the distance between the divs gets bigger when reducing the viewport width

Tags: html, css, position, size

I'm trying to practice my beginner html and CSS knowledge by making this template
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_band.htm
but the problem is when hitting inspect and reducing the width of the screen to see how my page looks like, I noticed that the div with the picture is getting smaller (which should as per the original one) but the div after it with the text (the one in green) is getting further away from it.
Is there a way to stop this from happening?

P.S. I made the div with the text in green to distinguish it for now only and the font awesome icons may not appear cuz I couldn't add the relevant CSS file of it here.

here is my page so far

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Band</title>
  <!-- google fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
     :root {
      --main-padding: 20px;
    }
    
    html {
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }
    /* start of nav bar */
    
    nav {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 99999;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    nav ul li,
    nav i {
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 15px 20px;
    }
    
    nav ul li:hover {
      background-color: lightgray;
      color: black;
    }
    
    nav ul li:hover a {
      color: black;
    }
    
    nav ul li a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .ddmenu {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .ddmenu::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      border: 5px solid;
      border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
      right: 5px;
      top: 50%;
    }
    
    .ddmenu:hover::after {
      border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
    }
    
    .ddmenu ul {
      display: none;
      background-color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .ddmenu:hover ul {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .fa-magnifying-glass:hover {
      background-color: tomato;
    }
    
    i.fa-bars {
      display: none;
    }
    
    @media (max-width:600px) {
      i.fa-magnifying-glass,
      li:not(.home) {
        display: none;
      }
      i.fa-bars {
        display: block
      }
      i.fa-bars:hover {
        background-color: lightgray;
        color: black;
      }
    }
    /* end of nav bar */
    /* start of posters */
    
    .posters {
      padding: 0;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 48px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .posters .container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      animation-duration: 12s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    
    .posters .container:first-of-type {
      animation-name: la;
    }
    
    @keyframes la {
      0% {
        z-index: 1;
      }
      33% {
        z-index: 1;
      }
      34% {
        z-index: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .posters .container:nth-of-type(2) {
      animation-name: ny;
    }
    
    @keyframes ny {
      0% {
        z-index: 0;
      }
      33% {
        z-index: 0;
      }
      34% {
        z-index: 1;
      }
      67% {
        z-index: 1;
      }
      68% {
        z-index: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .posters .container:last-of-type {
      animation-name: chicago;
    }
    
    @keyframes chicago {
      0% {
        z-index: 0;
      }
      67% {
        z-index: 0;
      }
      68% {
        z-index: 1;
      }
    }
    
    .posters .container>div {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .posters .container>div img {
      width: 100%;
      height: inherit;
    }
    
    .posters .container>div .text {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
      padding-bottom: var(--main-padding);
    }
    
    .posters .container>div .text h4 {
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    
    .posters .container>div .text p {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    @media (max-width:600px) {
      .posters .container>div .text {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    /* end of posters */
    /* start of band */
    
    section#band {
      padding: var(--main-padding);
      width: 100%;
      background-color: green;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    
    #band .container {
      padding: var(--main-padding);
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: lightgreen;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #band .text h3 {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: normal;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
    }
    
    #band .text p:first-of-type {
      color: grey;
    }
    
    #band .text p:nth-of-type(2) {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .name {
      max-width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding: var(--main-padding);
    }
    
    .name img {
      max-width: 90%;
    }
    
    @media (max-width:600px) {
      .name {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    }
    /* end of band */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#band">BAND</a></li>
        <li><a href="">TOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li class="ddmenu">MORE
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Merchandise</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Extras</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Media</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
    </nav>

  <!-- posters -->
  <section class="posters">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="la">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/la.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="text">
          <h4>Los Angeles</h4>
          <p>We had the best time playing at Venice Beach!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ny">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ny.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="text">
          <h4>New York</h4>
          <p>The atmosphere in New York is lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="chicago">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/chicago.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="text">
          <h4>Chicago</h4>
          <p>Thank you, Chicago - A night we won't forget.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- band info -->
  <section id="band">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text">
        <h3>THE BAND</h3>
        <p><i>We love music</i></p>
        <p>We have created a fictional band website. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
          ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur
          adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="name">
        <div>
          <p>Name</p>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Name</p>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Name</p>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a little weird to fix due to the absolute positioning -- I've made it so that the poster is always 100% viewport height and the image will cover the whole poster -- your issue was that the image was shrinking to fit the width leaving a bunch of empty space below it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Band</title>
  <!-- google fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
     :root {
      --main-padding: 20px;
    }
    
    html {
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }
    /* start of nav bar */
    
    nav {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 99999;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    nav ul li,
    nav i {
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 15px 20px;
    }
    
    nav ul li:hover {
      background-color: lightgray;
      color: black;
    }
    
    nav ul li:hover a {
      color: black;
    }
    
    nav ul li a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .ddmenu {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .ddmenu::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      border: 5px solid;
      border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
      right: 5px;
      top: 50%;
    }
    
    .ddmenu:hover::after {
      border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
    }
    
    .ddmenu ul {
      display: none;
      background-color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .ddmenu:hover ul {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .fa-magnifying-glass:hover {
      background-color: tomato;
    }
    
    i.fa-bars {
      display: none;
    }
    
    @media (max-width:600px) {
      i.fa-magnifying-glass,
      li:not(.home) {
        display: none;
      }
      i.fa-bars {
        display: block
      }
      i.fa-bars:hover {
        background-color: lightgray;
        color: black;
      }
    }
    /* end of nav bar */
    /* start of posters */
    
    .posters {
      padding: 0;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 48px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      height: calc(100vh - 48px);
      min-height: 300px;
    }
    
    .posters .container {
      position: absolute;
      inset: 0;
      animation-duration: 12s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    
    .posters .container:first-of-type {
      animation-name: la;
    }
    
    @keyframes la {
      0% {
        z-index: 1;
      }
      33% {
        z-index: 1;
      }
      34% {
        z-index: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .posters .container:nth-of-type(2) {
      animation-name: ny;
    }
    
    @keyframes ny {
      0% {
        z-index: 0;
      }
      33% {
        z-index: 0;
      }
      34% {
        z-index: 1;
      }
      67% {
        z-index: 1;
      }
      68% {
        z-index: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .posters .container:last-of-type {
      animation-name: chicago;
    }
    
    @keyframes chicago {
      0% {
        z-index: 0;
      }
      67% {
        z-index: 0;
      }
      68% {
        z-index: 1;
      }
    }
    
    .posters .container>div {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .posters .container>div img {
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      position: relative;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
    }
    
    .posters .container>div .text {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(calc(var(--main-padding) * -1));
    }
    
    .posters .container>div .text h4 {
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    
    .posters .container>div .text p {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    @media (max-width:600px) {
      .posters .container>div .text {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    /* end of posters */
    /* start of band */
    
    section#band {
      padding: var(--main-padding);
      width: 100%;
      background-color: green;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    
    #band .container {
      padding: var(--main-padding);
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: lightgreen;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #band .text h3 {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: normal;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
    }
    
    #band .text p:first-of-type {
      color: grey;
    }
    
    #band .text p:nth-of-type(2) {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .name {
      max-width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding: var(--main-padding);
    }
    
    .name img {
      max-width: 90%;
    }
    
    @media (max-width:600px) {
      .name {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    }
    /* end of band */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#band">BAND</a></li>
        <li><a href="">TOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li class="ddmenu">MORE
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Merchandise</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Extras</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Media</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
    </nav>

  <!-- posters -->
  <section class="posters">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="la">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/la.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="text">
          <h4>Los Angeles</h4>
          <p>We had the best time playing at Venice Beach!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ny">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ny.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="text">
          <h4>New York</h4>
          <p>The atmosphere in New York is lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="chicago">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/chicago.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="text">
          <h4>Chicago</h4>
          <p>Thank you, Chicago - A night we won't forget.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- band info -->
  <section id="band">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text">
        <h3>THE BAND</h3>
        <p><i>We love music</i></p>
        <p>We have created a fictional band website. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
          ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur
          adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="name">
        <div>
          <p>Name</p>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Name</p>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Name</p>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested solution. I learned some new features from it like inset and object-fit, but, as you can see in the original design https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_band.htm , the image does shrink to fir the width, and yet, it doesn't leave any space behind it or between it and the div next to it with the text.

Comment: @simokitkat yeah, it's just because you've absolutely positioned the images which means they're out of the document flow. So resizing the image doesn't affect the content below -- which is why the poster has a set height which the images then just fill. It'll take a biggish refactoring of what you have